# GMOCK : need to mock async behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest, googlemock

```
bool Test::someFun() {
    if (libFunction([](bool b) {
            if (b) {
                doThisWork();
            } else {
                doThatWork();
            }
        })) {
        return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

signature of libFunction is:

```
typedef void (*FUN)(bool);
bool libFunction(FUN f);
```

Hi Guys,
I need to test someFun function using Gtest/GMOCK. i need to mock libFunction which is written in C.
this libFunction takes a callback(lambda) argument.

Could you please help me with below 2 queries.

1. how to mock a C function (libFunction) ?
2. how to test callback which is passed as argument to libFunction as my actual implementation is in lambda which is need to be tested. is there a way to replace libFunction definition with dummy definition so that at run time of test case my dummy implementation will call instead of actual one and i can simulate the libFunction behaviour in dummy function.
   Could to please suggest better way to test this.

Comment: You cannot mock directly free function, you have to wrap it in interface first.

Comment: `if (cond) return true; else return false;` can be simplified by `return cond;`

Comment: You will not be able to test everything by using testing frameworks, if the code is not designed to be testable. But in C++ you can use low level trics to mock just any function by rewriting and generating machine code on the fly from some lib inside your program, or even from any dll even outside your program. That's for the case if you feel confident with patching techniques. I don't suggest this as a replacement for testing technique, but for code surgery you can try it https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34237/A-C-Style-of-Intercepting-Functions